# How to break on exceptions when using an error boundary

Tags: reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am using an `<ErrorBoundary>` component as described in the [docs on error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

However, it seems that Chrome's devtool setting "break on exceptions" no longer works to pause execution on a line of code that throws, which isn't surprising because the error boundary essentially catches all exceptions.

I can get Chrome to break on exceptions if I manually remove the `<ErrorBoundary>` but I am looking for a way to basically disable it from catching exceptions without having to make temporary source code modifications like that. How can I do this? Is there a "dev mode" setting that makes error boundaries re-throw the exception? Surely I'm not the first person who's wanted Chrome's "break on exception" to not become useless when I'm working in a React project using an error boundary?

I tried putting a breakpoint in `componentDidCatch()` but unfortunately this doesn't give the original callstack in the debugger, so it isn't very useful. I want to be able to inspect the callstack that threw the error, inspect the local variables and all that good stuff.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I wanted is pretty much covered by enabling "Pause on caught exceptions" in the Chrome devtools. This way even though the `ErrorBoundary` catches the errors, I still get a breakpoint on the original error.

[image]

The only caveat is that if this option is enabled on app load it hits an *enormous* amount of caught errors, because various polyfills and initialization code is sniffing out runtime state with `try... catch` blocks. So for my own errors that happen only on initial load it's quite a delicate dance to click that option at the right point.